# Was Luke able to see the face of living young Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

Given the scarcity or rareness of paper in the Star Wars Universe and subsequently, of family photos and portraits, and also knowing about the existence of recorded holograms, I ask if, aside from the shimmering and smiling Force ghost of young Anakin at the end of the 2004 DVD version of *Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi*, Luke ever had the chance to see his young father's face?

[image: Still image of Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi]

Comment: Since most of the Jedi archives and records were destroyed following Order 66 I'm guessing it is unlikely there is any digital imagery left for him to find. Unless he somehow got ahold of the like the holocron that Ezra has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has been addressed in canon, but in the Legends continuity, Luke had at least seen Anakin's face as a Jedi Knight by 35 ABY. In [*Dark Nest I: The Joiner King*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Nest_I:_The_Joiner_King), Luke finds a hologram recording of Anakin and Padmé in *Revenge of the Sith* while fixing R2-D2.

There are also some Legends books written as in-universe reference books that include images of Anakin's face (for example, the [*New Essential Chronology*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Chronology_(in-universe))), but it's unclear what form they took in-universe, or whether Luke ever read them.

And, finally, in an ambiguously-Legends-canon story called [*Sandstorm*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sandstorm_(comic)), 10-year-old Luke meets some kind of Force vision of 10-year-old Anakin, although it's not clear if he ever found out who he was.

Comment: The final paragraph, is that a vision of Anakin-as-a-child, or is it that Luke-as-a-child has a vision of Anakin?

Comment: @AakashM Both, actually - wording clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for rationale as to whether Luke would have recognized Anakin's force ghost if he appeared in his young adult form.  Therefore I'm thinking of sources prior to Endor.

There is a comic where Luke hears *stories* about Anakin, in [Star Wars: Empire: In the Shadows of Their Fathers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Empire:_In_the_Shadows_of_Their_Fathers), which occurs in 0 ABY prior to Bespin and Endor.  There is a flashback to the reader that shows Anakin as he appeared around Episode II, but Luke didn't see any holos or other imagery; he just heard the stories.